# POS Tagging in Dataframe pandas-Textblog

Tags: python, text-mining, textblob

I am trying to perform POS tagging to my text which are present in the dataframe. I tried using TextBlob, but I am not getting the desired result. My desired result is "a new column should be created with all the taggings".
Eg:"I like stackoverflow" and my new column POS_tagged should have [('I', 'PRP'), ('like', 'VBP'), ('stackoverflow', 'JJ')]

I tried using Textblob but it is working for one sentence. It is not working for series of sentences.

```
def postag(sentence1):
blob=TextBlob(sentence1)
return blob.tags

aspect_new["POS"]=aspect_new['tweets'].apply(postag)
```

I am getting below error

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'float'>
```

Could you please help me in achieving the same in textblob?

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be resolved using the following

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents
tweet=aspect_new['tweets'].tolist()
tw=[]
for i in tweet:
   tw.append(str(i))

tagged_texts = pos_tag_sents(map(word_tokenize, tw))
aspect_new["POS tags"]=tagged_texts
```